# Compare row value when records are not successive

Tags: mysql

I have a table wich holds the records for all the products purchases made. What I'm trying to do is to get a list of all the purchases made that contain one specific product to get a price variation history. I also want to display an icon showing if the price increased, decreased or is the same value as the previous record.

I almost made it work, however, the way I found to do it is based on the unique ID of each rows. The problem with this approach is that they are not sequential, so I can't rely on this method. What I need to compare is the date, but I'm finding it difficult to do.

First of all, here is my table structures:

```
**tb_purchase**
id | value_purchase | value_delivery | date
1  | 80.90          | 0.00           | 2019-07-01
2  | 24.90          | 5.00           | 2019-07-03
3  | 18.90          | 5.00           | 2019-07-03
[...continue]

**tb_purchase_product**
id | id_purchase | id_product | id_provider | price | quantity | total
1  | 27          | 33         | 2           | 16.90 | 1        | 16.90
2  | 27          | 87         | 2           | 34.90 | 1        | 34.90
3  | 28          | 64         | 2           | 19.90 | 1        | 19.90
4  | 29          | 33         | 3           | 15.80 | 3        | 47.40
5  | 30          | 48         | 3           | 18.90 | 1        | 18.90
6  | 31          | 33         | 1           | 15.80 | 1        | 15.80
7  | 32          | 33         | 3           | 17.90 | 2        | 35.80
[...continue]

**tb_provider**
id | name
1  | 'Mega Food'
2  | 'Best Market'
3  | 'Amazing Sales Store'
[...continue]
```

This is the query I did:

```
SELECT
    a.price,
    DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%d/%m/%Y') as 'date',
    c.name as 'provider',

    CASE
        WHEN a.price > d.price THEN 1
        WHEN a.price < d.price THEN -1
    ELSE 0 END AS 'variation'

FROM
    tb_purchase_product a,
    tb_purchase b,
    tb_provider c,
    tb_purchase_product d

WHERE a.id_product = :id_product -- {ex.: 33}
AND a.id_purchase = b.id
AND b.id_provider = c.id
AND b.date BETWEEN :date_initial AND :date_final
AND d.id = a.id + 1

ORDER BY b.date DESC
```

The expected result for `id_product = 33` is as follow, but I'm getting inconsistent results since it's comparing the value from the previous `id` and not previous record of the `id_product`. I'm also having trouble to fix this since I don't know how to mach the date when it's the first smaller date.

```
price | date       | provider              | variation
15.80 | 05/07/2019 | 'Amazing Sales Store' | -1
17.90 | 04/07/2019 | 'Mega Food'           | 1
15.80 | 03/07/2019 | 'Amazing Sales Store' | -1
16.90 | 02/07/2019 | 'Best Market'         | 0
```

> Note: `:id_product`, `:date_initial` and `:date_final` are passed via `php` array argument when running the application online.

Comment: Recommend looking at [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). Also recommend using the `FROM tb_purchase_product a JOIN tb_purchase b ON  a.id_purchase = b.id JOIN ...` as its harder to make a mistake.

Comment: @danblack About the `JOIN` statement I understood. But would you mind elaborate an aswer on the question itself? I'm new to mysql and still learning.

Comment: See "windowing" functions `LAG()` and `LEAD()` in MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested by [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james) in the comments, if you are working with MySQL 8+, you can make this much easier by using the [`LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) analytic function to return the previous row's price. You can also get the variation using the [`SIGN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_sign) function instead of the `CASE` expression, as demonstrated in the following query:

```
SELECT
  pprod.price,
  DATE_FORMAT(purch.date, '%d/%m/%Y')                                   AS date,
  prov.name                                                             AS provider,
  SIGN(pprod.price
     - LAG(pprod.price, 1, pprod.price) OVER (ORDER BY purch.date ASC)) AS variation
FROM
  tb_purchase_product AS pprod
  INNER JOIN tb_purchase AS purch ON pprod.id_purchase = purch.id
  INNER JOIN tb_provider AS prov ON purch.id_provider = prov.id
WHERE
  pprod.id_product = :id_product
  AND purch.date BETWEEN :date_initial AND :date_final
ORDER BY
  purch.date DESC
;
```

In this query I have also rewritten the joins using the `JOIN` syntax. Using the explicit `JOIN` syntax separates joining conditions from filter conditions more clearly, which, in my estimation, makes the code more understandable and easier to maintain (but your mileage may vary).

And with the use of the `LAG()` function there is no need to join a second instance of `tb_purchase_product`, which is another obvious difference of this query from the original.

One important note regarding this query is that, as written, it works for a single `id_product`, which should be all right based on your filter conditions. But if you ever need to run it for multiple products simultaneously, you need to introduce partitioning to the `LAG` function, like this:

```
LAG(pprod.price, 1, pprod.price) OVER (PARTITION BY pprod.id_product
                                       ORDER BY purch.date ASC)
```

The `PARTITION BY` subclause ensures that the previous `pprod.price` value is for the same product as the current row.

Comment: I had done this using `WHEN`, I didn't knew the function `SIGN`. It made the code a lot simple!! Also, since I'm ordering the date `DESC`, I had to use `LEAD` instead of `LAG` to work properly. But it helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: My online environment used MariaDb instead of MySql (if I'm correct) and the syntax on LEAD() was different. Just to let you know